# Proving that a matrix $U$, dependent on an inner product, is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, inner-products

Let $\{A_1,A_2...A_K\}$ be a set of linearly independent matrices in $M^\mathbb R_{n \times n}$.

Prove that the real $k\times\ k$ matrix $U$, given by:
$U_{ij} = (tr(A^t_iA_j))$ where $1 \leq i,j \leq k$, is invertible.

Not sure how to tackle this at all. My approach was to think of $U$ as a Gramian matrix in respect to the standard inner product, because obviously $U_{ij} = <A_i,A_j>$. I know that this should imply that $det(U) \neq 0$, but not sure why. Any help on this matter, and insight on general Gramiam matrices would be very helpful. Thanks a lot.

edit: I know that a Gramiam matrix is generally referring to inner products between vectors, but I'm hoping there's a general notion of it as just inner products.

Comment: But these matrices *are* vectors (of length $n^2$): when you call them linearly independent you are already treating them as vectors.  Everything you know about Gramian matrices does apply here, as you already made the connection between $U_{ij}$ and $\langle A_i, A_j \rangle$ with $A_i,A_j$ treated as vectors.  No need to pass to a more general notion of inner products.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Out of curiosity, let's assume that the entries of $U$ were given by, for example, the integral inner product of a set of linearly independent functions. Do the properties of Gramiam matrices still hold for $U$ in such a case? In particular - would $det(U) \neq 0$ still hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $U$ is noninvertible, then its columns form a linearly dependent set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely there exists a nonzero vector $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ such that for all $i$, one has:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\langle A_i,A_j\rangle=0.$$
Hence, for all $i$, one gets:
$$\left\langle\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j,A_i\right\rangle=0.$$
This means that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j\in\textrm{Span}(A_1,\ldots,A_n)^{\perp}$, but $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j\in\textrm{Span}(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$, therefore:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j\perp\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j,$$
which implies that:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j=0.$$
Finally, the $A_j$ are linearly dependent, a contradiction.

**Remark 1.** We even proved better, $\textrm{rank}(U)=\dim\left(\textrm{Vect}(A_1,\ldots,A_n)\right)$.

**Remark 2.** The above works for any real prehilbertian space.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I'm not sure how you achieved that the two sums are orthogonal to one another. Would appreciate a clarification.

Comment: I have edited my post, is it clearer? If you prefer, since $\displaystyle\left\langle\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j,A_i\right\rangle=0$, then:
$$\left\langle\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j,\lambda_iA_i\right\rangle=0.$$
Therefore, one has:
$$0=\sum_{i=1}^n\left\langle\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j,\lambda_iA_i\right\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jA_j,\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iA_i\right\rangle.$$